# Set table preferred width using Python Docx to Word file

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, python-docx

Background:

- Trying to create table in Word document using Python-Docx, requirement that table must be fixed width

Problem:

- No way to properly set fixed width that actually acts as fixed width. All widths are 'soft' settings meaning they all default to resizing itself if you modify the size of your viewing window (copy/pasting from Word to an email body and resizing the window makes the table resize itself)
- "Preferred Width" check box in the settings is never checked, even if I can modify the text width that is greyed out when the box is unchecked.

Already tried:

- Table.autofit and Table.allow_autofit = False
- Set column width directly: Table.columns[i].width = Inches(z)
- Set cell width directly for all cells: Table.rows[i].cells[j].width = Inches(z)
- Set table width directly
- Directly modify table XML to replace TblW property type and width value to 'Fixed' and desired width in DXA value.
- Directly modified table XML for column / cell width. Ran into issues with cell width not being recognized (tcW property doesn't exist).
- Tried all of the above concurrently. Was able to get the greyed text in the 'Preferred Width' settings box to change to the desired width, but no matter what I tried, I could never get the box to be checked in MS Word by default. This is what I need

Thanks!

---

### Edit below to add example code:

```
# Initialize Table
table = doc.add_table(rows=0, cols=test_table.shape[1])  # First row are table headers!
table.style = 'Table Grid'
table.autofit = False
table.allow_autofit = False
tbl = detractors_table._tbl  # get xml element in table
tblPr = tbl.tblPr  # We get an xml element containing the style and width
tblLayout2 = OxmlElement('w:tblLayout') #create XML element for layout
tblLayout2.set(qn('w:type'), 'fixed') # Set type to fixed width
tblW = tbl.xpath(".//w:tblW") # check if there is tblW element
if tblW:
    tblG = tblW[0]
    tblG.getparent().remove(tblG) # get location of tblW element in existing XML structure
tblK = OxmlElement('w:tblW')
tblK.set(qn('w:type'), 'fixed')
tblK.set(qn('w:w'), '23040')
tblPr.replace(test_table._tbl.tblPr.tblLayout, tblLayout2)
tblPr.append(tblK)

# Add row by row
row = table.add_row().cells
for j in range(test_table.shape[1]):
    q = detractors_table.columns[j]
    row[j].text = '{}'.format(q)
    p = row[j].paragraphs[0]
    b = table.cell(0, j)
    p.alignment = docx.enum.text.WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
    b.vertical_alignment = docx.enum.table.WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER

# Add the body of the data frame
for i in range(test_table.shape[0]):
    row = table.add_row().cells
    for j in range(test_table.shape[1]):
        tr = row._tr
        trPr = tr.get_or_add_trPr()
        trHeight = OxmlElement('w:trHeight')
        trHeight.set(qn('w:val'), "250")
        trHeight.set(qn('w:hRule'), "atLeast")
        trPr.append(trHeight)
        q = test_table.iat[i, j]
        row[j].text = '{}'.format(q)
        p = row[j].paragraphs[0]
        b = table.cell(i, j)
        p.alignment = docx.enum.text.WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
        b.vertical_alignment = docx.enum.table.WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER
        if i == (topissueslen - 1):
            e = topissueslen
            c = table.cell(e, j)
            c.vertical_alignment = docx.enum.table.WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER

style = doc.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'Helvetica Neue'
font.size = Pt(6)
tablelen = len(test_table) + 1
for i in range(tablelen):
    table.rows[i].cells[0].width = Inches(0.6)
    if table.rows[i].cells[0].text == '1':
        table.rows[i].cells[0]._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().append(
            parse_xml(r'<w:shd {} w:fill="63BE7B"/>'.format(nsdecls('w'))))
        table.rows[i].cells[0].text = ''
    elif table.rows[i].cells[0].text == '2':
        table.rows[i].cells[0]._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().append(
            parse_xml(r'<w:shd {} w:fill="FFEB84"/>'.format(nsdecls('w'))))
        table.rows[i].cells[0].text = ''
    elif table.rows[i].cells[0].text == '3':
        table.rows[i].cells[0]._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().append(
            parse_xml(r'<w:shd {} w:fill="F4B084"/>'.format(nsdecls('w'))))
        table.rows[i].cells[0].text = ''
    elif table.rows[i].cells[0].text == '4':
        table.rows[i].cells[0]._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().append(
            parse_xml(r'<w:shd {} w:fill="F8696B"/>'.format(nsdecls('w'))))
        table.rows[i].cells[0].text = ''
    table.rows[i].cells[1].width = Inches(1.0)
    table.rows[i].cells[2].width = Inches(0.8)
    table.rows[i].cells[3].width = Inches(0.6)
    table.rows[i].cells[4].width = Inches(1.2)
    table.rows[i].cells[5].width = Inches(1.5)
    table.rows[i].cells[6].width = Inches(2.0)
    table.rows[i].cells[7].width = Inches(2.5)
    table.rows[i].cells[8].width = Inches(3.5)
    table.rows[i].cells[9].width = Inches(1.0)
    table.rows[i].cells[10].width = Inches(1.0)
for i in range(0, 11):
    table.rows[0].cells[i]._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().append(
        parse_xml(r'<w:shd {} w:fill="C0C0C0"/>'.format(nsdecls('w'))))
    # issues_table.rows[0].cells[i].text.bold = True
make_rows_bold(table.rows[0])
```

---

[Screenshot of box not checked in MS Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RM6H.png)

Comment: Please share a minimal working code example, what you have tried and what shows your problem.

Comment: @Hermann12 added some edits for example code on table definition and a screenshot of the box being unchecked in Word regardless of setting the width as 'Fixed' directly via XML modification and setting cell widths individually

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, solved my own issue. Setting the table xml as 'Fixed' does not actually set it as fixed and is completely useless. Proper way to set this is via 'dxa' and ensure that you have 'dxa' everywhere for tables xml properties. Then this will show as checked box in Word when you look at the export